# JavaCV/OpenCV Memory Leak

Tags: java, opencv, memory-leaks, malloc, javacv

I have a small memory leak and I've narrowed it down to the following function:

```
 // Input image clusterMat 5-Means clustering, output number of clusters
 public static float contourDetection(CvMat src_image, Hashtable<Integer, Double> table, double gray_value) {
     CvMemStorage storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
     CvSeq contours = new CvSeq();
     CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();
     int sizeofCvContour = Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class);
     float total_num_clusters = 0.0f;

     // Find contours
     cvFindContours( src_image, storage, contours, sizeofCvContour, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

     for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) { 
         Integer contour_size = 0;
         if (ptr.total() > 0) {
             contour_size = (int)cvContourArea(ptr, CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 0);
         }
         table.put(contour_size, gray_value);
         total_num_clusters += 1.0f;
     }

     // Release storage
     storage.release();
     contours.deallocate();
     ptr.deallocate();

     return total_num_clusters;
 }
```

After I commented out the call to this function, the memory leak disappeared. Also, I call cvReleaseMat(src_image) in my main function, so that is not the source of the problem. Anybody see what the problem is? I've been staring at this for a couple hours now.... Thanks so much!

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it by changing CvMemStorage storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); to CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();. Not quite sure why that worked.